# Complex exponential function $f ( z ) = e^z$

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider the complex exponential function $f : \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ given by $f ( z ) = e^z$.

(a) Show that $f(-z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}$.

**My attempt**: If we substitute $-z$ in the given function equation we will obtain $f(-z) =
e^{-z}$ , but $e^{-z} = 1/e^z$. Is it OK?

(b) Find the domain and the range of $f$.

Comment: You need to prove that $e^{-z}=\frac{1}{e^z}$. Step one: what is the definition of the function $e^z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your attempt is OK.

For (b), notice that $e^z$ is defined for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, so its domain is $\mathbb{C}$.

If $z = x+iy$, then
$$
e^z = e^xe^{iy} \Rightarrow |e^z| = e^x
$$
Now, the range of $x \to e^x$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is all positive real numbers, so you can "hit" every circle of non-zero radius. Furthermore, by changing $y$, you can hit any point on a given circle.

Hence, the range of $e^z$ is $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: I have almost same problem as bebo has. I didn't understand your argument for range being $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. How you get from range of $e^x$ being $\mathbb{R}_+$ to range of $e^z$ being $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: Check that the map $y \mapsto e^{iy}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S^1$ is onto.